# Get a user's choice from prompt for push notifications with Airship and Flutter

Tags: flutter, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I want to get the choice of the user like (allow/don't allow) for receving push notifications. I use Airship for Flutter version `7.1.2`.

However, using the documentation and setting `Airship.push.setUserNotificationsEnabled(true);` allows the receiving of push notifications even if I click "don't allow". I check it with

```
Airship.push.isUserNotificationsEnabled.then((status) => { 
     debugPrint("Status: $status"),
)};
```

Any ideas how to get the user's choice and not the pre-defined value?

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution [in another documentation](https://docs.airship.com/reference/libraries/react-native/latest/classes/AirshipPush.html#setUserNotificationsEnabled)

"When `setUserNotificationsEnabled` enabled, it will cause the user to be prompted for the permission on platforms that support it. To get the result of the prompt, use `enableUserNotifications`."